# I need to find Special Characters in a string and display them in a label in C#

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

I need to find Characters contained in a string.
anything other than `A-Z(lower and upper) or numbers or () or /`,
those are the only characters allowed.

anything else (especially `à,è,ë,Ç,ç,ï and so forth`)are crucial to find and display in a label.

Basically I Stored everything from a text file to a string,using streamreader.
now every character other than [a-zA-z0-9]()/,need to be displayed in a label.

**the text file will look something like this:**

0145 Joane 5521  Maxin
0211 ChanÉ 2145  Spur
0124 Martôn 4512 btgames,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string BodyToCheck = richTextBox1.Text;

      //This is where I need coding....
  }




    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Quinell.Struthers/Test.txt");

        string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();

        richTextBox1.Text = body;
    }
```

Comment: guys 'n' girls - can we please stop voting to close and downvoting without bothering to explain to users ***why***.  The community will die.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/?cb=1

Comment: @QuinellStruthers - First: welcome to SO `:D` - I'll try to explain where others haven't. The best way to ask a question on SO - especially one like this - is to tell us what you are trying at the moment and what problems you're having with that (especially helpful are short snippets of code). If you haven't tried anything because you really don't know how to solve the problem; then you can say that - but you are likely to get 'go and learn' answers (and probably closed) unless you've found a potential solution and are having trouble understanding how to use it.

Comment: Andras, I wouldn't state it so drastically. But imho this isn't really a community either ;-)

Comment: @Joey Well I guess it's either a Community or a Club - I don't know; I suppose I'm thinking of people like friends of mine who say they hate SO because it's the ego show and that they're frightened of asking a question.  You're right, it won't die - but without new people joining and trusting it, it's reputation certainly will take a dive.

Comment: I have tried to store it as a char array and loop through,I tried a regex and then appended anything that doesn't follow the regular expression aswel as looping through the string

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code you are trying?

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: Can you also provide the text file or a link to the text file?

Comment: unfortunatly not. im sorry its a confidential file. but its a pretty big file with names and userid's ,just some names,like Chane contains a ñ,à,è, and so on,and i need to display those characters in a label

Comment: What happens if you add \n into the list of match characters it could be the line feeds that is throwing the issue.  Also can you atleast make up a sample that you expect to work that doesn't that way we are all singing off the same hymn sheet

Comment: ok,i added changes and its not the escape character i need i need to use UTF8

Comment: I've run your sample text through [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)  with the regex of `[A-Za-z0-9()/\n]` and it finds the non matched chars.  Have you tried attaching a debugger and checking the values of the strings as it could be a display problem with the label.

Comment: i havent,but i know the answer is in UTF-8,i just dont know what code to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a regex replace to remove the characters that are allowed and then display all those that aren't allowed in a label:

```
label1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "(?i)[a-z0-9()/]", "");
```

Comment: Otherway round isn't it?  Doesn't the OP want the illegal characters?

Comment: Well I tried this,but the label returns empty. I just need to display all characters other than the first group i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetSpecialCharacters(string str) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (char c in str) {
      if (!((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') | || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') | c == '.' || c == '_')) {
         sb.Append(c);
      }
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: If it is an extension method you need the keyword `this` before `string str`

Comment: Yeah thanks for mentioning Bob!! I have updated it.. Need not be an extension method!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
var regex=new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9()/]");
var toDisplay=string.Join("",regex.Matches(testString).OfType<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray());
```

EDIT Actually Joey's answer makes it far simpler, use a replace rather than grabbing all the values

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var regex=new Regex("[A-Za-z0-9()/]");
var toDisplay=regex.Replace(testString,string.Empty);
```

EDIT: Description of method 2

The first using needs to be at the top of your file, just like other usings.

The next line creates a Regular Expression object [Regex on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This regular expression will match any character that is in the range `A-Z`, `a-z` or `0-9` and additional would match `(`, `)` and `/`.

Finally the variable toDisplay is set to be the result of replacing all these matches with the empty string (effectively deleting them from the result). `testString` is the source string you wish to filter.  The code does not alter the source string merely sets toDisplay to be the result of the filter.

Comment: I dont really understand. Could you please explain a bit more the method you used here please

Comment: @QuinellStruthers I have updated the answer, does this explain it better?

Comment: Yes I understand it better,but the label remains empty